# error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(DashboardFragment,int,int,String[])

Tags: android

how child fragment

```
imaError:(31, 40) error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(DashboardFragment,int,int,String[])
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,List<String>) is not applicable
(actual argument DashboardFragment cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,List<String>) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,String[]) is not applicable
(actual argument DashboardFragment cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,String[]) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)ge send to parent fragment imageview
```

Comment: where is your code? post it

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, you have something like this:

```
new ArrayAdapter(this, ...);
```

where `this` is a `DashboardFragment`.

Replace that with:

```
new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), ...);
```

`ArrayAdapter` constructors take a `Context` (usually an `Activity`), not a `Fragment`. Call `getActivity()` on a `Fragment` to get a suitable `Context` to pass into the `ArrayAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, listdata);